# executing ffmpeg.exe from delphi with shellExecute

Tags: delphi, ffmpeg, shellexecute

I am trying to make a video from list of bmp images, when I execute from command line `ffmpeg -i img%5d.bmp -r 20 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22  output.mkv` everything is ok, but when I try to execute from delphi project, it doesn't work. I've tried:

```
parameters := '-i img%5d.bmp -r 20 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22  output.mkv';
ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar('c:\videos\ffmpeg.exe'), PChar(parameters), nil, SW_NORMAL);
```

I can't use `TProcess`, it has to be done with `ShellExecute`
Please help me with this one, tnx in advance :)

Comment: You reap what you sow when you call `ShellExecute`. It does not support sane error handling. Use `ShellExecuteEx` and get a proper error code. Then take it from there. However, `ShellExecuteEx` is still the wrong function. You need to call `CreateProcess` to do this *right*.

Comment: I am very new at this, I don't know how to handle parameters and special characters :(

Comment: I stand by what I said in my comment.

Comment: When i use ShellExecuteEx i get Too many actual parameters and there is a fiew arguments in CreateProcess which i don't understand

Comment: Which arguments don't you understand?

Comment: @hudyboy There's only one way to interpret "too many actual parameters". The reason why you aren't understanding any of this is that you are running around like a headless chicken. The only way you can call a function and pass too many arguments is by failing to read the documentation. How can you expect anything other than failure if you won't read documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice little piece of code I use. I am giving you this code but expect you to NOT just copy and paste. Please go through it to understand what it does.

The CreateProcess is what David spoke about. It is the best way to create and handle a process in Windows. Also note the WaitForSingleObject. That causes your execution to wait for Windows to finish before it returns after creating the process. You may of course remove the wait part. Also note the create flags.

It is called ExecuteAndWait. When you call it it will create a process and wait for it to finish:

```
function ExecuteAndWait(AFilename : String; AParameter : string;
                        ACmdShow : Integer; var AErrorOrExitCode : Cardinal): Boolean;
var
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
  S : String;
begin
  FillChar(StartupInfo,Sizeof(StartupInfo),0);
  StartupInfo.cb := Sizeof(StartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := ACmdShow;
  S := AParameter;
  UniqueString(S);
  if not CreateProcess(PChar(AFilename),PChar(S),nil,nil,False,
                       CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,nil,nil,
                       StartupInfo,ProcessInfo) then
    begin
      Result := False;
      AErrorOrExitCode := GetLastError;
    end
  else
    begin
      Result := True;
      WaitforSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
      GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess,AErrorOrExitCode);
      CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    end;
end;
```

Example:

```
var
  ErrorOrExitCode : Cardinal;
begin
  If not ExecuteAndWait('c:\windows\regedit.exe','"c:\windows\regedit.exe" "c:\test.reg"',SW_SHOWDEFAULT,ErrorOrExitCode) then
    Showmessage(Inttostr(ErrorOrExitCode));
```

Here I tell regedit to load a exported reg file. Note the double-quotes and also note that I specify the executable as the filename and as part of the parameter.

Adapt it to your needs.

Comment: `CreateNoWindow` is really what you want here, allowing you to hide the console. No need for `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` since we are starting a console app. Your code leaks two handles.

Comment: True but I gave this code as the code I use for different uses. Even though one would expect newbies to not research provided code one would hope for him to be the exception and check which different parameters can be used. At least that is what I hope for.

Comment: The other problem is that the second parameter of CreateProcess may be modified. So you can't pass a literal. You get away with this for CreateProcessA, but not for CreateProcessW. Add a call to UniqueString.

Comment: @David. As far as I can tell; Copying the AParameter string to a local variable inside ExecuteAndWait will be enough to fix the issue without needing to UniqueString it as well. Am I correct?

Comment: No you are not correct. Literals are stored in read only memory. Copying from one string var to another won't copy the payload. You'd need a SetLength, a character modify, a UniqueString etc. to make a copy into writeable memory.

Comment: Please consider my edit. Everywhere I have looked that seemed adeguate. I am not sure what you mean with character modify.

Comment: GetFileVersion in System.SysUtils also does it that way. The only difference is that the parameter in their function is a const parameter.

Comment: `UniqueString(AParameter)` would suffice and avoid the need for a new local variable. I find it hard to believe that `GetFileVersionInfo` really does still modify its argument. Perhaps in some ancient long forgotten version of Windows.

Comment: I've tried it in a new project  with several exe files and it works as long as there is no arguments, just like ShellExecute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71193/discussion-between-hudy-boy-and-blurry-sterk).